# Is there a MacOS (launchd) implementation for IHostLifetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, systemd, launchd

Microsoft has defined the `IHostLifetime` interface for WorkerServices to run as services on different platforms. (You can create a Worker Service project with `dotnet new worker` in the console).

If you want to run them as system services, you can use the extensions from Microsoft for systemd and Windows Services (See [Nuget Windows Service](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices/5.0.0-preview.7.20365.4) and [Systemd](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd/5.0.0-preview.7.20365.4)).

Is there already an implementation for MacOS (e.g. launchd) or would I need to do that one for myself if I want to support MacOS with my service, too?

---

See also https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/58b0c128d2672bada008d6e2b9e5b29ae70c2c4c/release-notes/3.0/api-diff/Asp.Net/3.0.0_Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd.md

and https://levelup.gitconnected.com/net-core-worker-service-as-windows-service-or-linux-daemons-a9579a540b77

Comment: Doesn't seem that way. Wonder how hard it would be to implement _some_ of the stuff in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions